# Creating object in loop and add to list

Tags: java, list, loops

Hello I have some problem to resolve. I need to create a loop where i create x person objects (x is a function parameter), and add it into a list.

```
class Person
{
    public int Age; 
    public String Name; 

    public Person(int age, String name) {
        this.Age = age;
        this.Name= name;
    }
}

class Solution {
    public int solution(int X) {
        // write your code in Java
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code showing what you've attempted so far.

Comment: This is my code

Comment: 1) Create an empty `List<Person>` 2) write a loop that executes `x` number of times and inside the body of that loop 3) create a `Person` object and 4) add that `Person` into the list.  Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: What is your question?  What is not working?  Your question seems too broad because it seems to just be asking for an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 7

```
  class Solution {
      public List<Person> solution(int X) {
        List<Person> list= new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<X;i++){
          list.add(new Person(age,name)); // pass age and name 
        }
        return list;
      }
    }
```

In Java 8

```
public List<Person> solution(int X) {
    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
            .limit(X)
            .mapToObj(i->new Person (age,name))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

or you can use parallel stream

```
public List<Person> solution(int X) {
     return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
            .parallel()
            .limit(X)
            .mapToObj(i->new Person (1,i+" name"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In Java 9

```
public List<Person> solution(int X) {
     return Stream.iterate(0, i -> i < X, i -> i + 1)
            .map(i->new Person(age,name))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use java 8 approach:

```
return IntStream.range(0, x).mapToObj(new Person(age, name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please note that you will create an x number of Person objects with the same properties.